# Disabled “Music with explicit content” checkbox

Tags: music

The “Music with explicit content” option in my Apple Music settings is disabled. I live in the US and should have no restrictions. What gives?

[image]

Comment: Has it always been this way? Did it just change without any actions on your part?

Comment: Not always been this way. Just noticed it recently. Changed without any input from me.